# Storing and Resetting LastModifiedDate for a file

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to add a text string to a file without updating the LastModifiedDate property. Is it possible to set the property to a variable before modifying the file, then reset the property to the stored value in the variable? I am attempting to do this on a folder containing hundreds or possibly thousands of files.

I think I have the right syntax to add the line of text I need and to set the last modified date to a variable but I'm not sure what syntax I need to reset the modified date in the for each loop.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Name *.bnf* -Recurse |Out-file C:\Temp\list.txt
cd C:\Temp
$FileList = Get-Content C:\Temp\Grammarlist.txt
(Get-Content $FileList) | 
  Foreach-Object {
  $temp = Get-Item $_.LastWriteTime}
    $_ # send the current line to output
    if ($_ -match "// Version") 
    {
        #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
        "// Release 19.1.4"
                }
} | Set-Content $FileList
```

Comment: have you considered searching for "powershell set modified date"?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the read/write `LastWriteTime` property of the file.

Adapted from [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-touch.html):

```
$oldDate = (dir test.txt).LastWriteTime
echo asdf >> test.txt
(dir test.txt).LastWriteTime = $oldDate
```